# Problems classifiying labeled text, wrong prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk

I'm playing with the different classifiers and vectorizers that scikit-learn provide so let's say I have the following:

```
training = [["this was a good movie, 'POS'"],
      ["this was a bad movie, 'NEG'"],
      ["i went to the movies, 'NEU'"], 
      ["this movie was very exiting it was great, 'POS'"], 
      ["this is a boring film, 'NEG'"]
        ,........................,
          [" N-sentence, 'LABEL'"]]

#Where each element of the list is another list that have documents, then.

splitted = [#remove the tags from training]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
X = HashingVectorizer(
    tokenizer=lambda  doc: doc, lowercase=False).fit_transform(splitted)

print X.toarray()
```

Then I have this vector representation:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

The problem with this is that I dont know if I vectorized right the corpus, then:

```
#This is the test corpus:
test = ["I don't like this movie it sucks it doesn't liked me"]

#I vectorize the corpus with hashing vectorizer
Y = HashingVectorizer(
    tokenizer=lambda  doc: doc, lowercase=False).fit_transform(test)
```

Then I print the `Y`:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Then

```
y = [x[-1]for x in training]

#import SVM and classify
from sklearn.svm import SVC
svm = SVC()
svm.fit(X, y)
result = svm.predict(X)
print "\nThe opinion is:\n",result
```

And here's the problem, I got the following insted of [NEG] which is actually the right prediction:

```
["this was a good movie, 'POS'"]
```

I guess I am not vectorizing right `training` or `y` target is wrong, could anybody help me to understand what's happening and how should I vectorize `training` in order to have a right prediction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will leave it to you to get the training data into the expected format:

```
training = ["this was a good movie",
            "this was a bad movie",
            "i went to the movies",
            "this movie was very exiting it was great", 
            "this is a boring film"]

labels = ['POS', 'NEG', 'NEU', 'POS', 'NEG']
```

**Feature extraction**

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
>>> vect = HashingVectorizer(n_features=5, stop_words='english', non_negative=True)
>>> X_train = vect.fit_transform(training)
>>> X_train.toarray()
[[ 0.          0.70710678  0.          0.          0.70710678]
 [ 0.70710678  0.70710678  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.89442719  0.          0.4472136   0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

With bigger corpus you should increase `n_features` to avoid collisions, I used 5 so that the resulting matrix can be visualized. Also note that I used `stop_words='english'`, I think with so few examples it is important to get rid of stopwords, otherwise you could confuse the classifier.

**Model training**

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

model = SVC()
model.fit(X_train, labels)
```

**Prediction**

```
>>> test = ["I don't like this movie it sucks it doesn't liked me"]
>>> X_pred = vect.transform(test)
>>> model.predict(X_pred)
['NEG']

>>> test = ["I think it was a good movie"]
>>> X_pred = vect.transform(test)
>>> model.predict(X_pred)
['POS']
```

EDIT: Note that the correct classification of the first test example is just a fortunate coincidence as I don't see any word that could have been learned from the training set as negative.  In the second example the word `good` could have triggered the positive classification.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me to understand. The issue I would like to clear is the `labelin`ing. What about if I have let's say just as an example: 1000000 `training` sentences, how can I label the training sentences and present it to the classifier if I just label by hand this 1000000 sentences and put them the label at the end of each sentence?.

Comment: If you mean in a text file, then you can choose a separator like `|`, and afterwards it will be easy to read them separately with pandas or the cvs module.

Comment: I mean something like this: `training = [["first sentence, 'LABEL'"], ["second sentence, 'LABEL'"]... ["N opinion, 'LABEL'"]]`. Because I would like to receive all the documents in a list, one document per list and then vectorize them.

Comment: I edited the question maybe It's more clear. Also I found interesting what you said about collisions how does the algorithm manage the collisions if I use the n_features parameter?. Could you provide me a reference?. Thanks

Comment: It is not difficult to convert from your format to the one I presented. You can ask for help here. May I ask why your data has such a weird format? What is your data source? It looks like there is a design problem somewhere.

Comment: I agree with you @elyase, I guess it's a design problem. The source data will be some opinions I'm crawling from the web. I thought that the format above was clear and expose what is happening when you do some text classification. So you recommend me a .csv format?. Something like this: `this is spam, SPAM` where the last element is the label of the data?. Thanks, nice year!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68047/discussion-between-ml-guy-and-elyase).

Comment: Yes, CSV + pandas for small data. This would be better `SPAM|this is spam` if you use .csv. It is easier to parse unambiguously, you can get into trouble using a comma as you separator when dealing with natural text. Other alternatives would be a sqlite database or even pickle two lists(`[sent1, sent2, ...]` and `[label1, label2, ...]`) or a lists of tuples(`[(sent1, label1), (sent2, label2), ...]`) to disk.

Comment: in fact I was thinking on use pandas. The problem is I dont know what would be a good aproach to label my own data set. I have 50 opinions in a directory in .txt format what can be a nice aproach with pandas?. By the other hand I was thinking on generate from the crawled opinions an arff file, but I don't know if this is possible with scikit-learn.

Comment: Do you have a .txt file per opinion?

Comment: No as a whole. Do you recommend me split them in order to have them one .txt per opinion?.